# I got a null reference exception on a Linq To SQL data context and I don't even really know where to start

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I just deployed a users and roles asp database to a website and I'm getting this exception

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

Line 41:   #endregion
Line 42:    
Line 43:    public UsersAndRolesDataContext() : 
Line 44:                base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"    ].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
Line 45:    {


Source File: d:\hosting\7122544\html\SSM\App_Code\UsersAndRoles.designer.cs    Line: 43

Stack Trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   UsersAndRolesDataContext..ctor() in d:\hosting\7122544\html\SSM\App_Code    \UsersAndRoles.designer.cs:43
   admin_ManageUsers..ctor() in d:\hosting\7122544\html\SSM\admin\ManageUsers.aspx.cs:11
   ASP.admin_manageusers_aspx..ctor() in c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ssm\5b123e8f\6bb9cf4c\App_Web_tz5adhff.10.cs:0
   __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_tz5adhff.Create_ASP_admin_manageusers_aspx() in     c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ssm\5b123e8f\6bb9cf4c\App_Web_tz5adhff.12.cs:0
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.CreateInstance() +32
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp) +109
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +31
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path) +37
   System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +334
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Comment: Do you have connection string named `ConnectionString` in the config file?

Comment: Oh, ok. That was it. It generated a connection string that works on my local machine, but not one that would work on a deployed website. Can I uprate comments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are likely missing connection string, named `ConnectionString` in the config file, so `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"    ]` returns null.

Answer (score 4):

You may be missing a connection string in your Web.config or App.config. Make sure that you have something similar to the following in your file.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdventureWorksEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=.\AdventureWorks.csdl|.\AdventureWorks.ssdl|.\AdventureWorks.msl;
         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=localhost;
         Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=60;
         multipleactiveresultsets=true'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Hrmm, thanks I just scripted the database without updating my webconfig, let me try that.